# Temporary disable a trigger for a single INSERT/REPLACE query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Is it possible to disable a single trigger on a table for a single query?

I have a batch job which is approx 150 rows - and I just want to have the trigger disabled ONLY for this batch job and nothing else?

```
// Disable this single trigger for shop_products table
REPLACE INTO `shop_products` (`mycolumnid`, `mycoltitle`, `Guid`) VALUES (11, 'hello', '23213-sda-423423');
REPLACE INTO `shop_products` (`mycolumnid`, `mycoltitle`, `Guid`) VALUES (14, 'bye', '53341-sfs-325243');
........
```

This is my trigger pre-set that i'd like to disable just this once but not actually remove it:-

```
BEGIN
   declare _GUID VARCHARACTER(64);
   set @GUID = UUID();
   SET new.GUID = @GUID;
END
```

Comment: Can you run `show create trigger [trigger_name]` and post the output in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow you to enable/disable individual triggers.

One thing that might work for you is to modify the trigger definition to only fire when you want it to.

For example you could modify the trigger definition so it only sets `new.GUID` if `new.GUID` is NULL. That way you can explicitly set a value for `GUID` and not worry about the trigger overwriting it.

For example:

```
   IF (new.GUID IS NULL)
   THEN
     SET new.GUID = @GUID;
   END IF;
```